# The Target "CheckMicrosoftNetNativeCompilerCompatibility" does not exist in the project

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

Using Visual Studio Community 2017 and I keep getting this error attempting to implement a UWP app. i tried to update windows sdk 16299 too .clean , build removed bin obj close VS but still these error come.

Comment: what is the target version/min version? is it 16299, or higher?

Comment: 16299 for both max and min

Comment: from where i can uncheck it "Compile with .NET Native tool chain option"?

Comment: i got this file "Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler.targets".

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT i got it and its already unchecked but whenever i delete bin obj file error occurs.

Comment: Please try this, run visual studio with administrator and modify the target to another version then rebuild it.

Comment: If the issue still exist , you could try install latest `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` and `Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler`  nuget package.

Comment: Restarting my VS 2019 instance and clearing bin and obj folders fixed mine.